# Convert a list of one type to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
  public class RelatorioResumoMovimentacaoECFDTO
  {
        [DataMember]
        public IList<AliquotaRelatorioMapaResumoDTO> 
        Aliquotas { get{return     MovimentacaoECF_Id.TotalizadoresParciais.????} }

        [DataMember]
        public MovimentacaoECF MovimentacaoECF_Id { get; set; }
  }
```

I need to convert the list "`MovimentacaoECF_Id.TotalizadoresParciais`" on a different list ...

something I could report that the X field of the list one is the Y field of the list two type when I convert KeyPairValue in dictionary

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);
```

Comment: So if you run the code to build the dictionary, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: And waht is the type of `TotalizadoresParciais` ?

Comment: TotalizadoresParciais is another type of list with another fields in this case other class TotalizadorParcialMovimentacaoECF

Comment: the code of dictionary is just a example of what i need... sorry about my english is dificult of explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do, but in the general case, `Select` may be useful here:

```
return MovimentacaoECF_Id.TotalizadoresParciais.Select(x =>
            new AliquotaRelatorioMapaResumoDTO {
               Foo = x.Foo,
               Name = x.SomeName,
               Id = x.Whatever,
               // ...
       }).ToList();
```